# Python create different functions in a loop

Tags: python

suppose I need to define functions that when the input is numpy array, it returns the numpy version of the function. And when the input is a cupy array, it returns cupy version of the function.

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
def tan(arr):
    return cp.tan(arr) if arr.__class__ is cp.ndarray else np.tan(arr)
```

I also need to create functions such as sin, cos,tanh etc. Is there a way to create those in a loop to avoid typos, or are there better ways? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To insert into the current module 3 functions with a loop:

```
from functools import partial

for fn in ('tan','sin','cos'):
  globals()[fn] = partial(lambda fname, arr: getattr(cp if isinstance(arr, cp.ndarray) else np, fname)(arr), fn)
```

How it works.. `globals()` returns a `dict` where you have every function & variable in the current module. So we insert lambda functions there for each func you want to define. In the lambda function we use `getattr()` to get the corresponding function from `np` or `cp` module and call it with `arr`.

The `partial()` is used to "freeze" the `fname` parameter.

Not sure if this is the best way but it works..

Comment: This works thanks a lot! there's a typo: use cp when arr is cp.ndarray else use np, so it should be `cp if isinstance(arr, cp.ndarray) else np`

Comment: @Sam-gege ooops.. that's what I get for writing it "blind" .. I will fix the example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with numpy and cupy but `arr.__class__ is cp.ndarray` seems to be an instance test, you should use `isinstance`

At first, you could try to create a `tan` function without using it directly

```py
def tan(arr):
    return getattr(cp if isinstance(arr, cp.ndarray) else np, 'tan')(arr)
```

I do not like that, too messy

```py
def tan(arr):
    src = cp if isinstance(arr, cp.ndarray) else np
    fn = getattr(src, 'tan')
    return fn(arr)
```

Now you can try to loop on it, but it will not so easy, `def xxx` can not be used directly. I recommend to use a `dict` or another workaround, but it is not the question.

To create function, you can add it to `locals()`

```py
for fx in ['cos', 'sin', 'tan']:
    def do_some_magic(fx):
        src = cp if isinstance(arr, cp.ndarray) else np
        fn = getattr(src, fx)
        return lambda arr: fn(arr)

    locals()[fx] = do_some_magic(fx)
```

Comment: The long version won't work because it will always call `tan` due to that being the last value of `fx`. The "one-liner" is not going to work either, it will call the functions in np/cp immediately in the loop and store the result into `locals()` as `fx`

Comment: I fixed the long version and remove the "one-liner" to leave yours

Comment: Umm.. the long version is now completely broken, sorry...

Comment: I tried it in a python interpreter and it works. Maybe you tried directly in the interpreter with the newline between `def` and `locals`, and yes this is not valid, the interpreter will suppose the new line is the for's end.

Comment: Hi @Joel, I tried your code but it raise an error saying "name 'arr' is not defined"?